# How to configure IIS server to redirect sub domains?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have a machine in my network which hosts a website using IIS 7.5. I can access this website from the internet, using port forwarding on my router. So far, so good. Now and want to host multiple websites using sub domains. Now I have this (dummy ip): `http://251.25.185.52/` and I can view my site. What I want now is to add sub domains to this ip: `http://site1.251.25.185.52/`, `http://beta.251.25.185.52/`, etc.

How do I configure this? I can't enter a new record in my router for `subdomain.192.168.0.51` since it only accepts ip addresses. And how do I need to configure IIS? I know I have to add a binding for the specific site, but what do I enter in the `hostname` box?

I have tried several things, but I keep getting the `This webpage is not available` error in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you are trying to do!
With http://251.25.185.52/ you are browsing to an IP number. http://site1.251.25.185.52/ is neither a valid IP number nor a valid IP name.

I understand what you are wanting to do, but this isn't the way to do it.

You want to register a domain name eg mydomain.com. You then want to point site1.mydomain.com and beta.mydomain.com to 251.25.185.52.

On your web server, you would create two sites and enter the host header as site1.mydomain.com on one and beta.mydomain.combon the other.

If you can already browse your website from the Internet, then there is no additional configuration required on your router.

Comment: Thanks! I do own a domain name, and I just created a subdomain and created a DNS A record to forward that subdomain to my ip-address. In my IIS I have set the bindings to `site1.mydomain.nl` and the same for the other. So, when that is all setup, it should work, right?

Comment: Yes it will work fine - the bindings for one site should have a host header of site1.mydomain.nl and for the other site should have a host header of beta.mydomain.nl. Please confirm that you have done that - in your comment above, you have said that they are both the same.

Comment: I am sorry, I was a little to vaque, I meant that that I did the same for `beta.mydomain.com`. Thanks again, now I am waiting till the DNS records are updated by my ISP. Can take up to 8-10 hours... :(

Comment: You can speed up the testing process by modifying the hosts file on your computer to include those new A records. That way you can test without waiting for the DNS update

Comment: Thanks, it works. But from another machine in the network, it doesn't work. It only works locally. Is there a way to get this working on all the other computers in my network?

Comment: The hosts file change is a temporary change that you make to the computer you are testing from. You will need to make this change to any computer that you want to test from. Once the public DNS changes go live, it will work from any computer.